# C++ to call python script to handle emailing

Tags: c++, python, smtp

On a server I have a C++ program which takes some input and writes some output to a file. After the file is generated, I want to send an email to a person with the corresponding link to the file.

I'd rather avoid dealing with SMTP from C++ itself, so I thought about having C++ using a system call to execute a python script, which would in turn handle the emailing process.

In C++:

```
system("python emailer.py foo@bar.com filetodownload.txt");
```

In Python:

```
import sys
email = sys.argv[1]
file = sys.argv[2]
// handle SMTP emailing...
```

I have a question about this simple approach. The C++ program is multithreaded, so there may be more than one thread wanting to call the python script to send an email. Is this a concern? Would one (again simple) solution be having a mutex variable in the C++ program which allows only one thread to call the python script at a time? Also, if there are better ways to go about accomplishing this task please let me know.

Comment: Can you push the emails to a database and have the python script poll it and send any email from there.

Comment: Actually the emails are already in a database (I have an interface with mysql from c++ and so was just thinking of passing it along that way). But if I understand your point, you mean call the script just to say that in general "a job is ready to email". The script then queries to find which jobs need to be sent. Is that right? 
Edit: That is, the script could find that potentially more than one email needs to be sent if two jobs finish at the same time.

Comment: Or just have the script running continuously and, when it runs out of jobs, waiting on something (whether something from the DB, or a simple POSIX signal or semaphore or Windows EVENT or whatever from the C++ code) that tells it "start looking again.

Comment: Anyway, is it possible that you'll get 500 jobs come in during the time it takes to send one email? If so, is it acceptable to try to send 500 emails simultaneously, or do you need to queue them up? (Remember that sending an email could conceivably fail by, e.g., timing out for 2 minutes on a DNS lookup.) If the answer to the first is "no" or the answer to the second is "it's fine", you don't need to do anything.

Comment: As a side note, `system` is usually not the best way to run subprocesses in C++, except in quick&dirty cases. If it's possible to use `popen`, `fork`+`exec`, `posix_spawn`, `CreateProcess`, etc. instead, it's usually worth doing.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use curl or boost to perform the SMTP in a separate thread with a shared memory queue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @abarnert, I'll look into those subprocess alternatives. To answer the previous concern, the system will most likely not be heavily used, so I doubt it would ever reach 500 jobs simultaneously. Perhaps if the send fails I can have python write such a notification to the database.

Comment: Alternatively, I've been looking into embedding Python into C++ recently. Works quite nicely, but you do need to write your own wrapper classes.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Good point. That may be more complex than what the OP needs here, especially if you want to run more than one… but it does have some huge advantages, like the ability to interact directly with the Python code from the C++ code (and vice-versa).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, Interesting. So the advantage to using curl/boost or even embedded python would be the ability to manage a queue of email jobs right? (something like abarnert alluded to with sending 500 emails simultaneously?) What if I had a shared queue in the C++ program that maintained all the jobs to be emailed, so that I can then synchronize the calls to the python script? Or is that just a messier way of going about it.  

Edit: just saw Alex's response, so I think direct interaction is the advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've shown I don't see any shared resource that would require any multi-threaded synchronisation. Each system call to python will result in a separate process.

Comment: This is more or less what I was getting at. Thanks for the clarification.